# SQLPlus Command Line In-line Set Commands

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, command-line

I have the need to run linux command line direct query, including  SET options.

The query by itself runs fine.

However, when I attempt to add set commands, it fails.

(my alias 'db' connects to SQLPlus successfully)

**OK/works fine (when sending single commands, issue seems to be with strining them together):**

```
$db<<<"SELECT * from mydb.mytable;"
$db <<<"show heading;"
$db <<<"SET heading OFF;"
```

**Not OK - Any variation of quotes/not quotes I try results in error:**

```
$db<<<SET HEADING OFF "SELECT * from mydb.mytable;"
$db<<<"SET HEADING OFF, SELECT * from mydb.mytable;"
$db<<<"SET HEADING OFF "SELECT * from mydb.mytable;"
```

**Results in complete error or:**

```
SQL> SP2-0158: unknown SET option ","
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put SET and SELECT in the same line, they are seperate commands. For example this works:

```
$ alias db='sqlplus -s user/password'

$ db <<< 'set heading off
set timing on
set echo off
select * from dual;'

X

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

If you insist on using a one-liner, you could try this:

```
$ echo -ne 'set heading off\nset timing on\nset echo off\nselect * from dual;' | db

X

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Comment: Thank  you Balazs Papp; both solutions work and I will use a mixture of the two!

Answer (score 0):

@Balaz gave me a great idea. Based on his answer, first set environment variable for your standard set commands, connection credentials, and create a function in your shell (can be done in your .bashrc file):

```
sets="set pagesize 0 heading off underline off feedback off"
ConnStr=user/passwd@servicename
function db { sqlplus -s $ConnStr <<< "$(echo -ne "${sets}\n${@}")" ; }
```

Then run sqlplus command like such:

```
db "select * from dual;"
```

Voila!